# Trouble calculating salary with commission using if statements C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

In this program we will be calculating the salary and the commission of a salesman.
He gets paid 10$ an hour plus commission based on the number of widgets sold. 
The first 50 widgets he doesn't receive any money, for the next 50 widgets (51-100) he makes 1$ commission.
for 101-300 he makes 2$ and for 300+ he makes 5$ per. The output should look like this (hours * 10 + 50*0 + 50*1 +200*2 + 100*5) but I don't know how to get that.  Thank you for any inputs

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool error(const string & msg);

int main() {
    double hours;
    double widgets; 

    cout << "How many hours did you work this month and how many widgets did you sell? " << endl;
    cin >> hours >> widgets;
    if (!cin) error("Your input is invalid"); 
    if (hours < 0) error("Your input can't be negative"); 
    if (widgets < 0) error("Your input can't be negative"); 

    hours = (hours * 10.00); // Salesman gets paid 10$ an hour 

    if (widgets <= 50) cout << 0; // Salesman doesn't get paid for less than 50 widgets sold

    if (widgets > 50 && widgets < 101) cout << widgets * 1.00; // 51-100 Widets sold = 1$ per

    if (widgets > 100 && widgets < 301) cout << widgets * 2.00; // 101-300 sold = 2$ per

    if (widgets > 300) cout << widgets * 5.00; // anything above 300 = 5$ per 

    /* my cout should look something like 
    hours * 10 + 50*0 + 50*1 +200*2 + 100*5 
    */
    cout << hours + widgets; 
}
bool error(const string & msg) {
    cout << "Error: " << msg << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
}
```

Comment: So you mean that your output should be a string like `"hours * 10 + 50*0 + 50*1 +200*2 + 100*5"`, or the result of the calcul ?

Comment: The results of the calculations should be in that format sorry if I didn't make it clear

Comment: Is this your own question, or a homework question assigned by your teacher?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely an assignment so I won't give away the answer but hopefully steer you toward your errors.

If you look at your logic and consider some test input you can easily see why it won't work as written. For example, consider `widgets = 500`.

> `if (widgets <= 50) cout << 0;`

The `widgets` are not equal to 50 so this logic won't trigger.

> `if (widgets > 50 || widgets < 101) cout << widgets * 1.00;`

The `widgets` are not in the range [51, 100] so this logic will not trigger but you want a calculation here. The same holds true for the next range [101, 300]. As written, only the final logic (`widgets > 300`) will trigger.

To fix this you'll need to keep a running total as you perform the calculations. Furthermore, you'll want the logic to trigger for every applicable range.

Using the same example of `widgets = 500` you want to apply calculations for all commission ranges. There are many ways to implement this but the general logic is:

- There are some number of `widgets`
- If there are more than 50 widgets figure out how many there are but do not exceed 100 and apply the calculation to this subset of the total widgets, conceptually there are now potentially some number of *remaining widgets*
- Continue processing the *remaining widgets* and applying the applicable commission calculation until there are no *remaining widgets* (there will definitely be any *remaining widgets* after the final commission range is reached, since it's all remaining widgets exceeding 300)

Comment: I've been looking over my code and realized a couple mistakes I made. Also I don't want the answer I need to figure this out on my own otherwise I'll never learn.  

if (widgets <= 50) cout << 0; was what I meant to put originally  
And I realized my OR statement won't work in this situation and I will need &&.  




And I will make a new integer which will consist of the running total. My only question is how will I be able to apply it to every range? If that's spoon feeding me the answer its okay you don't have to give it to

Comment: Yes, I intentionally avoiding how to apply all the commission ranges but I think I can add some more details that may help.

Comment: Also, I was thinking you needed the numeric result but if you just need to print the calculation expression you can keep the result in a `std::string` or print directly to the console.

Comment: I need to print the numeric result sorry that wasn't clear. I'm trying out what you said about more than 50 widgets and less than 100. It's definitely helping I'll let you know what I come up with

Comment: So I figured out how to get the remaining Widgets   

if (widgets > 50 && widgets < 101) cout << (widgets % 50) * 1.00;

Comment: `201 % 50` is `1` but if the input is `201` you want `50 * 1` for this commission range not `1 * 1`.

Comment: Another way to look at it is the size of the 1st range is 50, the size of the second range is 50, the size of the 3rd range is 200, and any remaining widgets are in the final unbounded range.

Comment: I get what your saying but I can't seem to translate that into code.

and why would I want to multiply 50 * 1?

Comment: Never mind I think I got it 1 second

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, given `201` widgets: `50` are in the 1st range (`50 * 0`), `50` are in the 2nd (`50 * 1`), `101` are in the 3rd range (`101 * 2`), no remaining widgets for the final range.

Comment: Yes everything you said is correct and I think I know how to do it I just don't know how to get the remainder to transfer over to the 2nd and 3 rd range

Comment: It's possible to track it with simple subtraction.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm doing right now

(widgets - 50 == widgets)       

(widgets - 50 == widgets + 50)       

and that's as far as I got so far

Comment: I can't do it I'm sorry my brain is fried @JamesAdkison

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result be a formatted string dont make the calculation. What you can use is a stringstream.

```
#include <sstream>

stringstream ss;
ss << hours << " * 10 ";
//...

//at the end
cout << ss;
```

You can do it with a string too, but some C code must be added to the cpp code

```
string cppStr;

char cstr[15];
sprintf(cstr, "%d", hours);

cppStr = cstr;
cppStr += " * 10";
//...
```

Comment: I don't know what a stringstream is so far in my class we have only covered strings , loops, and if statements. I know my if statements are incorrect and I need to fix them so they go off each other instead of each of them calculating an answer but I don't know where to start.

Comment: OK, if you dont know how to use stringstream, you can make your print format with a string, look at my added part in the code.

Comment: I'm sorry man I am looking at your code and I have no idea what I'm looking at it but I appreciate the help. James is helping me a bit but thank you